# How to create the same secret key both for Android and server

Tags: php, android, security, ssl, encryption

Based on the code of the following link

https://github.com/SeRPRo/Android-PHP-Encrypt-Decrypt

I have made my own implementation of an encryption/decryption mechanism between android and server (API written in PHP).

The example uses the same IV but in a real world case scenario someone would use a different one in each call. This is easy to implement since IV can be transferred without caring whether it is listened or not.

My question is how to create a different secret key for each new user during registration, both at android device and server side (The unique secret key will be stored in MySQL server side and SQLite or shared preferences on android side)?

If the secret key is created either at android or server and transmitted to the other part then it could be stolen by a "listener" and then the communication is no longer safe.

If the secret key is created by an algorithm, then the same algorithm must be implemented in both android and server. The android apk file could be decompiled and as a result the algorithm could be found and then the secret keys predicted.

It seems like vicious circle. Any safe way to create the same unique secret key for each user both at client side (android) and sever side without having to take the risk to transmit it through a POST request to the other part?

PS. I am aware of SSL, https but I am looking for a simpler solution since I am trying to protect data such as login details (username/password) and not "highly sensitive data" (eg credit cards etc.). Reading about how to implement SSL/https rather confuses me than making the things simpler for me.

Comment: Clearly your "simpler" solution that doesn't confuse you has created a problem for you.... so perhaps SSL would have been simpler after all than trying to reinvent it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Using a symmetric key on both sides (server and client) is highly risky in this kind of architecture, due to a reason that you mention: If someone cracks your app, they will probably also crack the key. The situation is even worse as you mention that you're managing highly sensitive data. Usually (not in this kind of situation), crackers will try to crack any application, but with such sensitive data, they will triple efforts (and probably they will be successful).

That's why this kind of architecture's recommended approach is an asymmetric encryption system, because you don't have to store any key (the public key could be available in some public HTTP address), and this way you can use it to encrypt messages, but it's just the server which holds the private key the one that will be able to decrypt those messages. I recommend using `SSL/TLS` here.